# why i don't have sign in with apple in xcode

Tags: xcode

Why I don't have Sign in with Apple option in Xcode, so confused..Can any one tell me how to fix this
[image]

Comment: you need to assign your target to a team and add an apple id  in preferences

Comment: Is Personal Team ok? I am Personal Team and there is no sign in option.

Comment: do you use free or paid developer account? some capability need a paid developer account

Comment: Ah..I am using a free account, I see.. I will try to solve it in this way, an expensive way lol

Comment: I am not sure about sign in with apple, but capabilities like push notification and cloudkit/icloud need a paid account. I think because it use apple resource it need a paid account

Comment: problem solved after I upgraded my account, thanks bro

Comment: Someone downvoted the question for no reason. I have the same question but with different scenario: my client IS part of the "Apple Developer Program" and I am member of their team. Yet I cannot find that capability in Xcode therefore I cannot compile the app.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, you need a paid developer account to access such capabilities:
https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/

Answer (score -1):

you need apple developer account
where you need to create identifier and
check Sign in with Apple
then use that identifier for protect and add new certificate
then you able to find Sign in with Apple in xcode