# SwiftUI - Sign In with Apple - Xcode 13.1

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication

I need to authenticate the users of my app through the use of login with apple. Until recently I have always added the `capabilities` of **Sign in with apple** but now I can't find it anymore when I use **Xcode 13.1**.

[image]

Has anything changed that I don't know?

Now with **Xcode 13.1** if I need to authenticate my users with **"sign in with apple"** what should I do?

Comment: It is strange, maybe the Apple account that you are using not is on the ADP (Apple Developer Program membership) the capabilities for your Apple apps depend on it: https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/

Comment: @JorgeLuisPeñaLopez Until now even though I was using a test developer account (without paying the apple develop program) it seemed to work .. So now some capabilities only work if my developer account has been paid for?

Comment: Apparently yes, I have found that other people have had the same or something similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62768842/why-i-dont-have-sign-in-with-apple-in-xcode https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/icloud-capability-not-available-in-xcode/4980

Comment: @JorgeLuisPeñaLopez ok Thanks!!

Comment: @kAiN Yep, I noticed this recently too. I have a paid and a non-paid account, and capabilities like these only show up when using the paid account. Before, even if you added the capability, you couldn't compile it on a free account because it would error.